# Should Docker Container's resource usage increase or decrease with vertical scaling?

Tags: docker, resources

If I increase the CPU or Memory Usage of Docker by let's say a core/memory every time it's run using this:

`docker run --rm --name application-name --cpus 6 application-name`

`docker run --rm --name application-name --memory 2g application-name`

Where I increase the cpu from 1, 2, to 6 and memory from 2g to 6.

Does the CPU and memory usage of an application when vertically scaled with increasing CPU and memory limit, decrease or increase?

So far I tried to measure the resource usage and with increasing limit (scaling), the resource usage for both memory and CPU decreases. But if I scale horizontally, the resource usage increases. Shouldn't both have resource usage increasing? Or did I measure wrong for vertical scaling?

At the back of my head, I thought since we're giving more CPU/memory limit in vertical-scaling, the resource consumption will still be the same and thus since it's an overall percent of higher memory/CPU, the percent of resource usage will be less.

I'm new to this so apologies for poor wording, just curious if there's a general trend of higher or lower resource usage with vertically scaling up.